# scala Stream transformation and evaluation model

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

Consider a following list transformation:

```
List(1,2,3,4) map (_ + 10) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
```

It is evaluated in the following way:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4) map (_ + 10) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
List(11, 12, 13, 14) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
List(12, 14) map (_ * 3)
List(36, 42)
```

So there are three passes and with each one a new list structure created.

So, **the first question**: can `Stream` help to avoid it and if yes -- how? Can all evaluations be made in a single pass and without additional structures created?

Isn't the following Stream evaluation model correct:

```
Stream(1, ?) map (_ + 10) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
Stream(11, ?) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
// filter condition fail, evaluate the next element
Stream(2, ?) map (_ + 10) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
Stream(12, ?) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
Stream(12, ?) map (_ * 3)
Stream(36, ?)
// finish
```

If it is, then there are the same number of passes and the same number of new `Stream` structures created as in the case of a `List`. If it is not -- then **the second question**: what is `Stream` evaluation model in particularly this type of transformation chain?

Comment: Just because a new `Stream` object exists doesn't mean a pass was made over the entire collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't avoid it by using `Stream`.
But you do can avoid it by using the method `collect`, and you should keep the idea that everytime you use a `map` after `filter` you may need a `collect`.
Here is the code:

```
scala> def time(n: Int)(call : => Unit): Long = {
     |   val start = System.currentTimeMillis
     |   var cnt = n
     |   while(cnt > 0) {
     |     cnt -= 1
     |     call
     |   }
     |   System.currentTimeMillis - start
     | }
time: (n: Int)(call: => Unit)Long

scala> val xs = List.fill(10000)((math.random * 100).toInt)
xs: List[Int] = List(37, 86, 74, 1, ...)
scala> val ys = Stream(xs :_*)
ys: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(37, ?)

scala> time(10000){ xs map (_+10) filter (_%2 == 0) map (_*3) }
res0: Long = 7182

//Note call force to evaluation of the whole stream.
scala> time(10000){ ys map (_+10) filter (_%2 == 0) map (_*3) force } 
res1: Long = 17408

scala> time(10000){ xs.view map (_+10) filter (_%2 == 0) map (_*3) force }
res2: Long = 6322

scala> time(10000){ xs collect { case x if (x+10)%2 == 0 => (x+10)*3 } }
res3: Long = 2339
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to avoid intermediate collections is to use `view`.

```
List(1,2,3,4).view map (_ + 10) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
```

It doesn't avoid **every** intermediate, but it can be useful.  [This page](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html) has lots of info and is well worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, If you always iterate through the whole collection Stream does not help you.
It will create the same number as new `Streams` as with the `List`.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I understand it as follows:

Stream is a lazy structure, so when you do:

```
val result = Stream(1, ?) map (_ + 10) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
```

the result is another stream that links to the results of the previous transformations. So if force evaluation with a foreach (or e.g. `mkString`)

```
result.foreach(println)
```

for each iteration the above chain is evaluated to get the current item.

However, you can reduce passes by 1, if you replace filter with `withFilter`. Then the filter is kind of applied with the map function.

```
List(1,2,3,4) map (_ + 10) withFilter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
```

You can reduce it to one pass with flatMap:

```
List(1,2,3,4) flatMap { x =>
  val y = x + 10
  if (y % 2 == 0) Some(y * 3) else None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala can filter and transform a collection in a variety of ways.

First your example:

```
List(1,2,3,4) map (_ + 10) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (_ * 3)
```

Could be optimized:

```
List(1,2,3,4) filter (_ % 2 == 0) map (v => (v+10)*3)
```

Or, folds could be used:

```
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(List[Int]()){ case (a,b) if b % 2 == 0 => a ++ List((b+10)*3) case (a,b) => a }
```

Or, perhaps a for-expression:

```
for( v <- List(1,2,3,4); w=v+10 if w % 2 == 0 ) yield w*3
```

Or, maybe the clearest to understand, a collection:

```
List(1,2,3,4).collect{ case v if v % 2 == 0 => (v+10)*3 }
```

But to address your questions about Streams; Yes, streams can be used
and for large collections where what is wanted is often found early, a
Stream is a good choice:

```
def myStream( s:Stream[Int] ): Stream[Int] = 
  ((s.head+10)*3) #:: myStream(s.tail.filter( _ % 2 == 0 ))

myStream(Stream.from(2)).take(2).toList  // An infinitely long list yields
                                         //   36 & 42 where the 3rd element
                                         //   has not been processed yet
```

With this Stream example the filter is only applied to the next element as it is needed, not to the entire list -- good thing, or it would never stop :)